# Start Recursive Script as systemd unit

Tags: centos, systemd, recursive

I want to execute a script on startup. The script is recursive and calls itself.
When I added systemd unit for the same, it is executing but getting stopped in 1 min due to `DefaultTimeoutStartSec`. It assumes that my script has not yet started.

Following is the service file I have created

```
    [Unit]
    Description = My Desc
    After = network.target

    [Service]
    Type = forking
    ExecStart = /root/my_recursive_script.sh

    [Install]
    WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

I know I can make this service as working by adding `TimeoutSec` to infinity but that would be workaround. When I execute my service with

```
    systemctl start myservice.service
```

it does not leave the cursor until timeout encounter.

1. What is the proper way to make systemd units work with recursive script?
2. Do I need to make changes in my script to make it executable like daemon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is you have set the service type to `forking`.  Systemd is waiting for you `ExecStart` to fork to background before proceeding.  You need to change the type to `simple`.  See [the manual](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html)